# Power in electrical circuits

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

Why does $P=i^2R$  apply only to transfer of electrical potential energy to thermal energy in a device with resistance while $P=iV$ apply to electrical energy transfers of all kinds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does P=i^2R apply only to transfer of electrical potential energy to thermal energy in a device with resistance

How would you expect a formula involving a term "R" to apply to something that doesn't have any characteristic called "R"?

> while $P=iV$ apply to electrical energy transfers of all kinds?

This formula applies to all electrical devices (or more correctly, to any branch in a lumped circuit).

The alternate formula involving $R$ is derived from this one, based on Ohm's Law

$$V=iR.$$

If you substitute this into the power formula $P=iV$ you can get either

$$P=i(iR)$$

or

$$P = \left(\frac{V}{R}\right)V$$

Both of which simplify to well-known formulas for the power consumption of a linear resistor ($P=i^2R$ or $P=V^2/R$).

Comment: If we connect the two terminals of a cell with an ideal conducting wire, to where is the the energy transferred to ( since according to $P=iV$ there is energy transfer) ?

Comment: @GauthamShankar, 1. There is no such thing as a perfect conducting wire, so some power will be converted to heat in the wire. 2. There is no such thing as a perfect voltage source, so some power will be converted to heat in the cell itself. Practically speaking, the majority of the heat will typically be generated in the cell.

Comment: If you had a perfect voltage source, and want to think about what happens if you get close to an ideal wire, use the form $P=V^2/R$ and take the limit as $R\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of voltage as energy change upon moving a charge. So you know the energy changes by QV for every charge that moves across. That gives a rate IV. It didn't have to be an Ohms law resistor in this derivation.